# Haskell problem "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

Tags: haskell

I'm new in Haskell and kind of struggling with an issue I'm not even sure I understand so I could use some help to fix it...

I'm trying to create a simple function that, given three digits "a" "b" and "c", would display all combinations where "a" is smaller than "b" and "b" i smaller than "c" while incrementing them. For instance "4", "5" and "6" would give something like "456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789"

So far my code looks like this :

```
  axx :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
  axx (x) (y) (z) = if y == 8 && z == 9
                        then x + 1
                        else x
  
  ayy :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
  ayy (x) (y) (z) = let y = if z == 9 && y < 8
                                then y + 1
                                else if z == 9 && y == 8
                                then x + 1
                                else y
  
  azz :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
  azz (x) (y) (z) = let z = if z == 9
                                then y + 1
                                else z + 1
  
  my_print_comb :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
  my_print_comb (x) (y) (z) = do print (x)
                                 print (y)
                                 print (z)
                                 if (x /= 7 && y /= 8 && z /= 9)
                                     then do
                                         putStr ", "
                                         let x = axx (x y z)
                                         let y = ayy (x y z)
                                         let z = azz (x y z)
                                         my_print_comb(x y z)
                                     else putStr "\n"
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" error message regarding the line where my "azz" function starts. I tried looking for similar case on the web but without any luck so far.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: In your code, `axx` is first defined as a function of 3 variables. In expression `axx (x y z)`, it is then used a a function of one variable, because you tell the compiler that `x` is a function, to which you pass y and z as arguments. Try with just: `axx x y z`. And generally, unlike C/C++/Fortran/Java/Python, you do **NOT** need parentheses to pass arguments to functions. Note that in Haskell, *implicit* function call has a very high precedence. It is *explicit*  function call, that is the dollar `$` operator, which has a low precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a lot of parentheses: `axx (x) (y) (z)` -> `axx x y z`. `print (x)` should be written `print x`.

You have to remove `let y =` and `let z =` Li-yao said.

Also remove the parentheses

```
  let x = axx (x y z)
  let y = ayy (x y z)
  let z = azz (x y z)
  my_print_comb(x y z)
```

->

```
  let x = axx x y z
      y = ayy x y z
      z = azz x y z
  my_print_comb x y z
```

Otherwise `x` is interpreted as a function applied to `y` and `z`.

Using function application manifest what you wrote is `axx $ ((x $ y) $ z)` when you meant `((axx $ x) $ y) $ z`.

```hs
infixr 0 $

($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) = id
```

In general intead of checking `axx x y z = if x == 8 && z == 9 then .. else` you use pattern matching `axx 8 y 9 = ..`.

Use `undefined :: a` to develop iteratively

```
axx :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
axx x 8 9 = x + 1
axx x y z = undefined
```

Try to separate the `IO` out of `my_print_comb`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `let y =` and `let z =` in `ayy` and `azz`.